# How to catch all required filed error message with Spring Web Service's Custom Validation Interceptor

Tags: java, xml, spring, validation, xsd

In Spring WS 2.0.0 for `PayLoadValidatingInterceptor` by validation my xsd request file, only one required field error message is shown when validation error found.
I wanna get is that all required field error messasges which is (`nillable=false`) in xsd schema file.

In my Customer.xsd schema file.

```
<xs:element name="firstname" nillibale="false" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="middlename" nillibale="false" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="lastname" nillibale="false" type="xs:string"/>
```

And, When validating with `PayLoadValidatingInterceptor`, only one fault message is shown which is that 'firstname' is required.
But, in my point of view, i have to get all fault messages ('firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname') are required when validating.

In my configuration file,

```
<sws:interceptors>
     <bean id="validatingInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
         <property name="schema" value="classpath:schema/Customer.xsd"/>
         <property name="validateRequest" value="true"/>
         <property name="validateResponse" value="true"/>
     </bean>
</sws:interceptors>
```

P.S: No logging is used and I test with SoapUI Tool.

And, Output is..

```
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
     <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring xml:lang="en">Validation error</faultstring>
     <detail>
          <spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="springframework.org/spring-ws">cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'cus:customer' is not complete. One of '{"customer.model.web.insurance.ace.org":firstname'; is expected.</spring-ws:ValidationError> 
     </detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

In my point of view, I want to get is that..

```
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
     <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring xml:lang="en">Validation error</faultstring>
     <detail>
          <spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="springframework.org/spring-ws">cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'cus:customer' is not complete. One of '{"customer.model.web.insurance.ace.org":firstname'; is expected.</spring-ws:ValidationError> 
          <spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="springframework.org/spring-ws">cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'cus:customer' is not complete. One of '{"customer.model.web.insurance.ace.org":middlename'; is expected.</spring-ws:ValidationError>
          <spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="springframework.org/spring-ws">cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'cus:customer' is not complete. One of '{"customer.model.web.insurance.ace.org":lastname'; is expected.</spring-ws:ValidationError>
     </detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

Comment: AFAIK the validator returns all invalid fields, what you do with handling this exceptions/errors/faults is up to you (and how you defined the schema/response etc.). In yuor logging all the errors should show up (they are logged at WARNING level).

Comment: <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">Validation error</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="http://springframework.org/spring-ws">cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'cus:customer' is not complete. One of '{"http://customer.model.web.insurance.ace.org":firstname' is expected.</spring-ws:ValidationError>
         </detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>

Comment: I validated with PayloadValidationInterceptor but it can show only one fault code for 'firstname'. It could not show fault codes for all 'firstname', 'middlename' and 'lastname'. Do you think that I should need to write custom validation interceptor?

Comment: Please add the output to your initial post not as a comment. As mentioned check your logging to see if all the validation errors are available (it should be logged at WARNING and I assume you have some logging setup). Also which version of Spring WS are you using? And please add some configuration to see how you have set things up.